# RecyclerView is not showing data from Firestore

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, android-recyclerview

```
recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.companyFeed_RecyclerView_CompanyList);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        ArrayList<Company> myCompanyData = new ArrayList<>();
        myCompanyData.add(new Company("Company marc","trustworthy",null));
        db.getFirestore().collection("companies").addSnapshotListener((value, error) -> {
            assert value !=null;
            for (QueryDocumentSnapshot snapshot : value) {
                Company c = Deserialization.deserializeCompany(snapshot);
                myCompanyData.add(new Company(c.getName(),c.getDescription(),null));
                System.out.println("company: " + myCompanyData.get(1).getName());
            }
        });
        CompanyAdapter myCompanyAdapter = new CompanyAdapter(myCompanyData, CompanyFeedActivity.this);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(myCompanyAdapter);
```

My RecyclerView only shows the element "Company mark" before the snapshotListener. My database works perfectly fine. System.out.println shows me the right element with the right name.

Is there any better way to access the elements or did I make something wrong?

This is how my database looks like:

```
Firestore-root
  |
  --- companies (collection)
        |
        --- company 1 (document)
             |
             --- name: Marc
             |
             --- description: test
        |
        --- company 2 (document)
             |
             --- name: Lucas
             |
             --- description: test2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is that the listener is triggered after the adapter is created and set. You need to explicitly call `myCompanyAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged` after the data list is modified.

Please try the below code

```
 recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.companyFeed_RecyclerView_CompanyList);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        ArrayList<Company> myCompanyData = new ArrayList<>();

        CompanyAdapter myCompanyAdapter = new CompanyAdapter(myCompanyData, CompanyFeedActivity.this);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(myCompanyAdapter);
        myCompanyData.add(new Company("Company marc","trustworthy",null));
        db.getFirestore().collection("companies").addSnapshotListener((value, error) -> {
            assert value !=null;
            for (QueryDocumentSnapshot snapshot : value) {
                Company c = Deserialization.deserializeCompany(snapshot);
                myCompanyData.add(new Company(c.getName(),c.getDescription(),null));
                System.out.println("company: " + myCompanyData.get(1).getName());
            }
            myCompanyAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
        });
```

Comment: Hey, I can see the elements now however the problem with this solution is, it isnt adding dynamically. For example if my database is very big it will take a long time to load and show the activity. However the purpose of recyclerview is that it only shows the first 10-20 elements and loading the other elements while scrolling

Comment: I think what you are looking for is pagination, https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors, you can first query the first 10 element, then add a onScrollListener to detect user has scrolled nearly to the end, and query the next 10 data and add it to the recyclerView,